# downgrade directive component from angular 2 to angularJS is not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

Here is my angular 2 component:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[my-component]',
  template:`<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class MyComponentClass {
  @Input() myComponent: string;

...
```

This allows me in angular 2 app use this as directive on any html tag, for example:

```
<div [myComponent]="'my text string'"></div>
<span [myComponent]="'my text string'"></span>
```

But when taking the same component downgrade to be used in angularJs app:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myComponent', downgradeComponent({component: MyComponentClass , inputs: ['myComponent']}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory);
```

Now this will not work:

```
 <div [myComponent]="'my text string'"></div> // or
<div [my-component]="'my text string'"></div>
```

Only if I use it as component like

```
<my-component [my-component]="'some text'"></my-component>
```

What have I done wrong?
I don't want it to be used as a new html tag, but as a directive that can be added to any html element (directive).

Answer (score 1):

I've met the same issue and found a word around at: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16695#issuecomment-336456199

Answer (score 0):

Try using `downgradeNg2Component` instead of `downgradeComponent`:

```
import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';
import {myComponent} from './my-component.component.ts';

let upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();

.directive('myComponent',  
   upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(myComponent))
```

Check this [useful post](http://blog.rangle.io/upgrade-your-application-to-angular-2-with-ng-upgrade/#downgradingcomponents)!

Comment: I get downgradeNg2Component does not exists on type of upgradeAdapter

Comment: Are you importing `UpgradeAdapter` from `'angular2/upgrade'`? And also declaring `upgradeAdapter` as `new UpgradeAdapter()`?

Comment: import {UpgradeAdapter} from '@angular/upgrade';

Comment: Nope, the new UpgradeAdapter says: supplied paramters do not match any signture or call target

Comment: I updated my answer. Remember that you have to import the component that will then be passed as parameter in `downgradeNg2Component()`. Hope it helps man, let me know! :D

Comment: BTW - I have tried to downgrade a simple directive written in angular 2 to be used in angularJS, it just don't work, Component works but when you want them to be directived seems its not :(

Comment: Seems to compile at last, but how you declare inputs of the directive?

Answer (score 0):

change "myComponent" to "mycomponent" and delete hyphen .The reason for all this capital letter ('C') and hyphen